# Convert PNG to Base64 Encoded String in UltraEdit or Similar Windows Editor

Tags: windows, text, base64, text-editor

I would like to open an existing PNG in UltraEdit or other text editor and save the base64 string value. What is the best way to accomplish this using UltraEdit or any other Windows editor.

Comment: The [Image Optimizer for Visual Studio](https://github.com/madskristensen/ImageOptimizer) extension (for Visual Studio) lets you copy any image as a base64 dataURI to the clipboard. But that might be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor supports Python plugins. Here is new plugin which does your job.

- Call menuitem "Plugins / Make Plugin".
- Enter some caption of new menuitem and enter this contents of `__init__.py` file which will be opened:

```
import os
from base64 import b64encode
from cudatext import *

class Command:
    def run(self):
        fn = dlg_file(True, '', '', 'PNG|*.png', '')
        if not fn: return
        s = open(fn, 'rb').read()
        s = b64encode(s).decode()
        x, y, x1, y1 = ed.get_carets()[0]
        ed.insert(x, y, s)
```

- Restart editor. After call of your item in Plugins menu, plugin asks for path of PNG file, and inserts file as Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Text editors aren't the best tools for working with binary data, however this can be accomplished using a tiny [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) script if that's an option for you:

```
console.log(require("fs").readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString("base64"));
```

You could even wrap it up in a little batch script that you can drop an image file onto an have it generate the base-64 version:

```
@echo off
node toBase64.js "%~1" > "%~1.base64"
```